# PHP and FCGID goes away for alsmot 1 minute every hour

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mod-fcgid

I'm running an apache2 server on Debian 7

Php files are handled by fcgi. After a migration of server all is working fine. But alsmost every hour the serveur doesnt answer to http requests (http client is waiting for a response for many seconds until an error 500 happens). This last for alsmost 1 minute, then all work fine.

This happens alsmost once every hour.

Didn't find any reason, any cronjob that would match.

But in the log i have 3 related kinds of errors :

```
mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /var/www/user/wrapper
Premature end of script headers: script.php
mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 40 seconds
```

Also, memory usage, and cpu usage are normal during the minute the server doesnt answer and put that in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that you are simply running out of processes to deal with requests. You probably want to increase your MaxClients and/or MaxSpareServers.

You may also wish to check your PHP configuration settings (FCGI settings not php.ini)

Comment: How may i determine the correct value for that ?

Comment: Drop the timeout values by half and double the max amount of processes allowed and play with the values some :)

Comment: It looks like i dont have MaxSpare or MaxClient into /etc/apache2/mos-enabled/fcgid.conf